# How to identify root issue of local web server via IIS or Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, iis, localhost

I am very new to coding but have basic knowledge of troubleshooting and website design in HTML/Java.

Using Windows 10, IIS, Visual Studio Code, Python & Oracle

I am helping a friend with a project where they inherited a server and files for a program/platform. As soon as the data was transferred and server physically moved the webpage stopped working.

We have the original computer with all the original files

The server seems to be based in IIS though the inetpub/wwwroot files appear to be standard downloads and not any custom designations.

inetpub/wwwroot only contains iisstart

Pinging the IP address shows it is active and responding.

Chrome returns error "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" when using https://LOCALWEBSITENAME

or "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when using https://www.LOCALWEBSITENAME

- Any suggestions on where to start identifying the main disconnection issue?
- Tips on locating the original web server files?

Comment: What about trying `http://` not `https://`?

Comment: http:// returns the IIS Start page & https:// returns error "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Comment: Maybe you haven't set up ssl? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

Comment: feedback is appreciated! SSL certificate is confirmed set up on the working computer and all certificates are valid for another few years. The errors have not changed.

Comment: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error appears when the domain name system cannot resolve a website’s URL into an IP address, making the web browser unable to reach it. "inetpub/wwwroot" is the path of Default site. If your project is deployed on IIS, you should check the site bindings. About troubleshooting, you can enable Failed Request Tracing to get fail logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing.

Comment: If you learn what are site bindings https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html and then understand how a typical Python web app might be hosted on IIS, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ then I think you can answer your own question.